# Magento: Admin - Dynamic Form with dependency rule and dynamic values

Tags: php, forms, magento

Is it possible to make a form (In Backend Custom Tab) which contains for example two dropdown fields and the second field depends on the first one with its values beeing also dependend of the selection from first field.

Here an example:

```
[Attributes] <-- 'Select' field with all Attributes
[Values]     <-- 'Select' field with all Values of selected Attribute in above field
```

Comment: Check this link http://www.atwix.com/magento/fields-dependency-in-magento-admin-forms/

Comment: Thanks. That covers up the dependence rule. But I still dont know how to get the dynamic values for the second field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use after_element_html key to add custom html or javascript.

```
$fieldset->addField("xxx", "text", array(
                "label" => Mage::helper("xxx")->__("Field"),
                "name" => "xxx",
                "class" =>"validate-number",
                "after_element_html"=>"<script>your javascript code here</script>"
            ));
```